# REST API for gitlab CI?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have set up a CI pipeline, and it is working well. However, I still have to go to a web interface and click buttons - is there an API for this functionality, specifically the CI part? I know there is a REST interface to gitlab as such, but I still haven't spotted the parts that handle CI - does it exist?

Comment: You mean something like https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/ ?

Comment: Something like that, but perhaps with details about how to use it in general and for CI specifically. When I looked at that page, it seemed rather sketchy.

Comment: I have seens plenty of entries in the left menu talking about pipelines and jobs if I remember well.

Comment: Well, there are entries about CI/CD in the menu on the left, but that is not about REST API calls, as far as I can tell.

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/jobs.html#play-a-job as an example.

Comment: Oh, jobs! I suppose it makes sense, but I was looking for variations over the theme 'CI' and similar. Thanks for your help - if you write it up as an answer, I'll accept it and vote it up as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the [full API documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/).

You should more specifically be interested on the sections regarding [jobs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/jobs.html) and [pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/pipelines.html)